# Auto click yes in javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, alert

I would like to automate a click in a javascript file used to convert xlsx to csv.

I will provide a snippet of the script that gives the alert.  After the alert is given, is there any way to click yes to what is being asked automatically?  I am using this to create a formatting utility.

```
  // Determine whether or not linefeed characters should be removed.
  var msg = "Would you like to remove linefeed characters from all cells?";
  var title = "Remove Linefeed Characters";
  var removeLf = alert.Yes == alert(msg, title, alert.YesNo + alert.Question);
  // Click 'Yes' button here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always need the user click on YES... ¿why you don't just assign `true` to `alert.Yes`?

Comment: I figured it was something simple.  That does what I want thanks!

Comment: You should post it as an answer if it's something else.